# 'HttpContext' could not be found on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, httpcontext

Linux, .Net Core 2.2.105, VS Code.

I've done 'dotnet new webapi', and trying to add a class which inherits HttpContext, however VS Code complains

> The type or namespace name 'HttpContext' could not be found

I have using 'System.Web;' at the top, my projects.assets.json has

> "ref/netcoreapp2.2/System.Web.dll": {},

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core does not have a HttpContext in System.Web, which is classic ASP.NET and not ASP.NET Core.

To see how you can access ASP.NET Core's HttpContext (namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`), refer to the documentation: [Access HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2)